# Updating graphql schema without a server restart in apollo 2

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js

My project has a declarative way of defining schema and resolvers, which is maintained in a separate repository. My graphql server polls the result of this to look for updates to the schema.

Using apollo-server-express@1, I had direct access to the graphqlExpress middleware, so when the schema changed I could construct a new instance of it and throw away the old one, something like this

```
const { graphqlExpress } = require('apollo-server-express');

let api;

const constructAPI = () => {
    try {
        const newSchema = createSchema();
        api = graphqlExpress(({ headers }) => ({
            schema: newSchema,

        }));

        logger.info({ event: 'GRAPHQL_SCHEMA_UPDATED' });

};

schemaPoller.on('change', constructAPI);

module.exports = router => {

    // Note that we wrap the api controller in a function that passes
    // the original args through because a new api controller is generated
    // every time the schema changes. We can't pass express a direct
    // reference to the api controller on startup, or it will
    // never update the reference to point at the latest version of the
    // controller using the latest schema
    router
        .route('/')
        .get((...args) => api(...args))
        .post((...args) => api(...args));

    return router;
};
```

In apollo-server-express@2, access to the middleware is hidden away, and there are 2 new, more declarative ways of using the library, neither of which - at first glance - appear compatible with updating the schema without stopping the server, fetching the new schema and starting again with the new data, which is downtime I'd like to avoid.

Can anyone suggest a way of getting this setup to work with apollo@2?